# Session Destruction / Logout Odd Issue

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, logout

My site uses a simple login system that creates a cookie for the username and a login session.  If someone visits home.php and the login session is set as logged in, they are pushed to the logged in area.  Otherwise they login using a simple form and handler page.  To logout users click a link which takes them to logout.php which contains the following code:

```
<?

session_start();

setcookie(username, $username, time()-360000);

session_start($_SESSION['login']);
$_SESSION["Login"] = "no";

header("Location: home.php");
session_destroy();

?>
```

Here is what is going on.  Users who click the logout button are kicked out to the page home.php correctly.  If they refresh the page they remain on the home.php page.  Seems good so far.

However, if they navigate away from the home page, they are brought into the logged in area.  And if they go to the url of a logged in area they are not kicked out (because the session checking script confirms the session value is set as logged in).

I'm dumbfounded.  I am not a PHP pro by any means though--what am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

To invalidate your session you only need to delete your cookie.

```
setcookie("username", "", time()-360000);
```

will do the job. please note that username should be in quotes `"` otherwise it will not refer to a cookie name.

So your code in logout will be like below

```
<?
    session_start();
    setcookie("username", "", time()-3600);
    header("Location: home.php");
?>
```

When User Logs in and is validated you need to set a cookie for them and then redirect them to your authenticated url

You also need to check your cookie at start of each page in your authenticated area like following

```
<?
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_COOKIE["username"]))
        header("Location: home.php");
?>
```

hope this helps

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) is another sample of setting, using and deleting cookies